# Status 304 for AFNetworking is still getting data

Tags: ios, django, afnetworking-2

I'm calling my server using the below blocks:

```
void (^ successBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id jsonDictionary) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id jsonDictionary) {
    NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", jsonDictionary);
};

void (^ failureBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failed: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
};
```

On my server, which is written in Django, I send `HttpResponseNotModified` when the data is not modified anyway. The app however, sometimes it runs in the `successBlock` with the json response (probably from a previous request) and then other times it goes to the `failureBlock` with the 304 status code. Is there a reason for this? I can confirm for a fact that my server is sending the 304 status code as I went through it with debug points. Why is AFNetworking sometimes getting a cached object? and where is it getting it from?

Basically sometimes when the 304 status error is sent, the `successBlock` is run...it should always be hitting the `failureBlock` since it got the status error code.

Comment: This seems like the expected behavior. `AFNetworking` is caching responses and since you are returning 304, it is using the object it has cached. In the case there is no cache available, it is failing. At which point you should retry, specifying a different cache header so your server will not return 304 again but instead the actual resource.

Comment: Is there a way to force it to not cache the response?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, so you should probably do some further reading (http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/02/20/afimagecache-vs-nsurlcache/ is a good place to start) but if you set the cachePolicy of your NSURLRequest to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData you should always fetch the remote data.

Comment: You can put this as an answer and I will accept. Turns out you were right.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make your client always fetch and ignore 304 status codes, you need to set the `cachePolicy` of your `NSURLRequest`s to `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`.

More information can be found about this and other options at http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/02/20/afimagecache-vs-nsurlcache/ and http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/. I'd say NSHipster is a good source as Mattt wrote AFNetworking.